# Any existing DNS resolver project for windows? Both C++ or C# will do

Tags: c#, c++, dns

I've been trying to build a DNS resolver in C# since last week, which is a painful process.

Though I've made some progress (say, I can parse the data of a DNS Message correctly), it became more and more likely to me that this may not be the right job for C#.

I have to be prepared in case I had to port to C++. But it is best not do it from scratch again.

So is there any project for Windows that can be used to parse a received DNS message or construct one to send?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this, perhaps it helps:
http://www.ibusy.com/articles/software-development/boost-net-dns-library-2.html
It build on top of boost::asio 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 1):

[`bind`](http://www.isc.org/software/bind) has a whole suite of tools (with source code) for doing DNS queries and much, much more.  It's liberally licensed (MIT-like license), so you can use it even in commercial projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try Heijden DNS: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DNS_NET_Resolver.aspx